# Python data error: ValueError: invalid literal for int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below dataframe

```
customerid                          birthdate   
8a1edbf14734127f0147356fdb1b1eb2    45
8a2ac4745091002b0150a144bcbe58b7    24
```

customerid is the unique identifier of type `non-null object` . Howerever I want to convert it into an integer for me to be able to sort and apply functions on it.

I convert with the below `df['customerid'] = pd.to_numeric(df['customerid'], errors='coerce')` and the column is now converted to `non-null float64`. However the ids are now NaN

```
customerid  birthdate   
nan         45
nan         24
```

I have basically lost the customerids. How do i convert to integer and still have the values of customerid and not nan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like need convert hex values to integers:

```
df['customerid'] = df['customerid'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))
print (df)
                               customerid  birthdate
0  183593693287801188128470244383876914866         45
1  183655524454060116426046384483461912759         24
```

EDIT:

Missing values are expected, because converting non numeric values (strings) to numeric is not possible - parameter `errors='coerce'` return NaN values for each value:

```
df['customerid'] = pd.to_numeric(df['customerid'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
   customerid  birthdate
0         NaN         45
1         NaN         24
```